# Do we need to added firebase custom code for flutter ios project

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPBBNi2Ou6o&t=596s
In above video tutorial they are adding two line
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
do we need to add it if we are using flutter ios project?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need it. the docs not mentioning it. here the docs [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

pod 'Firebase/Auth' is used  when you are building Hybrid IOS Apps using swift, it will connect your IOS app to firebase. In case of Flutter you dont need to mention that

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup